# SQL split one row in to four rows

Tags: sql

I have a SQL database with seven columns as below

```
version1; 1993; name; 233; 254; 291; 244
version1; 1994; name; 333; 354; 391; 344
```

The last four columns represent quarterly values ​​and I would like to pick out one value per row, so each row is extracted to four rows. In addition, I would like to add a value (a column that keeps track of the quarters provided). The wish is that the two data rows above are reported as

```
version1; 1993; 1; name, 233
version1; 1993; 2; name; 254
version1; 1993; 3; name; 291
version1; 1993; 4; name; 244
version1; 1994; 1; name, 333
version1; 1994; 2; name; 354
version1; 1994; 3; name; 391
version1; 1994; 4; name; 344
```

Is there any easy way to do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which SQL? (My SQL, SQL Server etc)

Answer (score 1):

This would give you the output in desired format:

```
SELECT version, year, 1 as 'quarter', name, quarter1_value 
FROM myTable

UNION

SELECT version, year, 2 as 'quarter', name, quarter2_value 
FROM myTable

UNION

SELECT version, year, 3 as 'quarter', name, quarter3_value 
FROM myTable

UNION

SELECT version, year, 4 as 'quarter', name, quarter4_value 
FROM myTable
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `UNION` to achieve your desired result. This works for both MySQL and SQL Server. You can use `UNION` like this:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT version, year, 1 as 'quarter', name, quarter1_value FROM tt
UNION
SELECT version, year, 2 as 'quarter', name, quarter2_value FROM tt
UNION
SELECT version, year, 3 as 'quarter', name, quarter3_value FROM tt
UNION
SELECT version, year, 4 as 'quarter', name, quarter4_value FROM tt
) a
Order by Year, QUARTER
```

## [*See this SQLFiddle*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/709fc/4)

Answer (score 1):

You can use either a `UNION ALL` or an `UNPIVOT` for this. `UNPIVOT` is not available on all RDBMS.

`UNION ALL` (See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/85b81/1)):

```
select col1, col2, col3, 1 quarter, col4
from yourtable
union all
select col1, col2, col3, 2 quarter, col5
from yourtable
union all
select col1, col2, col3, 3 quarter, col6
from yourtable
union all
select col1, col2, col3, 4 quarter, col7
from yourtable
```

`UNPIVOT` (See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/85b81/6)):

```
select col1, col2, col3, 
  cast(replace(field, 'col', '') as int) - 3 quarter, 
value
from 
(
  select col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7

  from yourtable
) u
unpivot
(
  value 
  for field in (col4, col5, col6, col7)
)u
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT version, year, name, '1', quarter_1 FROM table

UNION

SELECT version, year, name, '2', quarter_2 FROM table

UNION

...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a cross join to a table with the four quarters then use a case statement to select the appropriate quarter:

```
SELECT
  ORIG_TABLE.VERSION,
  ORIG_TABLE.YEAR,
  QUARTER_NAMES.Q_NAME,
  ORIG_TABLE.NAME,
  CASE QUARTER_NAMES.Q_NAME
    WHEN 1 
      THEN ORIG_TABLE.Q1_VALUE
    WHEN 2
      THEN ORIG_TABLE.Q2_VALUE
    WHEN 3
      THEN ORIG_TABLE.Q3_VALUE
    WHEN 4
      THEN ORIG_TABLE.Q4_VALUE
 END Q_VALUE
FROM
  ORIG_TABLE
    CROSS JOIN 
    (
       SELECT 1 Q_NAME
       UNION SELECT 2 Q_NAME
       UNION SELECT 3 Q_NAME
       UNION SELECT 4 Q_NAME
    ) QUARTER_NAMES
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a sql view. Use a sql split function which return a row based on index. You can get some help from the link http://geekswithblogs.net/AngelEyes/archive/2007/04/12/111504.aspx

Answer (score 0):

No DBMS has been supplied, so I'm going to throw a couple of SQL-Server specific ones out just in case.

```
-- SAMPLE DATA
DECLARE @T TABLE (Version VARCHAR(15), Year INT, Name VARCHAR(5), Col1 INT, Col2 INT, Col3 INT, Col4 INT)
INSERT @T VALUES
    ('version1', 1993, 'name', 233, 254, 291, 244),
    ('version1', 1994, 'name', 333, 354, 391, 344)

-- CROSS APPLY VALUES
SELECT  Version, Year, RowNum, Name, Value
FROM    @T
        CROSS APPLY 
        (   VALUES 
                (Col1, 1), 
                (Col2, 2), 
                (Col3, 3), 
                (Col4, 4)
        ) t (Value, RowNum)

-- UNPIVOT
SELECT  Version, Year, REPLACE(RowNum, 'Col', '') [RowNum], Name, Value
FROM    @T
        UNPIVOT
        (   Value
            FOR RowNum IN ([Col1], [Col2], [Col3], [Col4])
        ) upvt
```